# How do I avoid "Access Violation" during asynchronous database connections?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ado.net, task-parallel-library, sqlconnection

### Goal: Using ExecuteAsync correctly.

I know my application itself is at least *pretty close* to correct because it executes correctly *once*, so I know I can eliminate the usual suspects of firewalls, wrong database passwords, procedure names, etc.

```
private async Task<T> executeAsyncHelper<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> then)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(name, conn))
        {
            parameters.Select(p => cmd.Parameters.Add(p))
                .ToImmutableList(); 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (IDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                return then(rdr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### The Issue: Access Violation on the *Second* SqlConnection.Open()

The method gets called twice on the same procedure. The first time, it successfully updates the database. The second time, the whole thing dumps out on `conn.Open()` with "Access violation." Importantly, it's not throwing an exception. Rather, the whole debugger exits with a negative status code.

These are the last two lines of the debugger output (The rest of the debugger output looks normal):

```
The program '[6904] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.  
The program '[6904] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This behavior is 100% repeatable.

### Hypothesis: Connection Pooling and Asynchronicity

As far as I can see, the most probable cause is that there's some problem with opening two connections asynchronously, but I don't immediately know what to *do* with that hypothesis. I've written the method as safely as I know how.

Secondarily, I checked to see if my Azure SQL Server instance had any unusual limitations on it. It's a basic instance, but I doubt that's the issue since I would expect a SQL exception (that the debugger will break on and show a normal stack trace) if that were the problem.

### Environmental information

- Azure SQL Server 2016
- Windows 10
- .NET Core 2.1
- Visual Studio 2017

### Conclusion

Does anyone see any problem with the way I've implemented this or have any suggestions to learn more about the error?

Comment: Where, and what, is `parameters`?  Can you include that also?  Not saying it's the cause, but it's the only thing I can't see :)

Comment: Also, your function is `async Task<T>`, but you're not awaiting on the `Func<>`, so I suggest you change the signature of the function passed in to also be asynchronous, e.g. `Func<IDataReader, Task<T>>`

Comment: Also, what does your debugger say?

Comment: Okay, numbered by comments: 
1. `parameters` is injected in the constructor with the connection string and the procedure name. The contents when it fails is really close to what it is when it succeeds, so I don't think that's the cause. Never hurts to ask though.
2. Just refactored, but it didn't seem to help. 
3. Debugger isn't really saying things. When I step over `conn.Open()` the debugger just exits with the above logs. 

Working hypothesis: I'm wondering if my code is embarrassingly parallel. I'm going to try synchronicity and see if that helps me. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: You do get a +1 for a wonderfully formed question, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty confident I figured it out. It didn't actually have anything to do with the precise line where the program was dying.

Rather, the program was overflowing the stack elsewhere on a different thread. The `conn.Open()` was a red herring, even though that's where the debugger always pointed just before it failed. My guess is that `conn.Open()` is just resource intensive enough to put it over the edge to make it look like that was causing it.

For future reference, if you get "Access violation," refactor to synchronous code, and then the debugger will be able to walk straight through and actually throw the StackOverflowException instead of just crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private async Task<T> executeAsyncHelper<T>(Func<IDataReader, Task<T>> then)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(name, conn))
        {
            parameters.Select(p => cmd.Parameters.Add(p))
                .ToImmutableList(); 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (IDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                return await then(rdr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the changes to the signature, and awaiting on `return`.

Comment: I'll work on this, but I'm curious: why convert `then` to async only to await it?

Comment: @EleanorHolley, because you're method is `async` and returns a `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you can check that you're not hitting a connection limit, you can do exec sp_who2 and see how many connections are on your sql server. If there are a lot of connections shown on the sql server, that maybe the cause due to resource issues. Have you try running this code in the regular synchronously and did it cause the same issue? Is there anything on your connection string that limits the number of connections? Just some theory to throw out since I don't see the context of this code.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  `sp_who2` is only really useful if you're not sure if you're disposing of connections properly.  I see no issues with the code presented, and I do not believe it is down to the connection itself, due to the `Access Violation` nature of the problem.

Comment: The point of using sp_who2 is to see if there are other connections on the box, not only the one your application is consuming, just so we can eliminate a possible cause. The code is not a problem as is, but we have to put it into context, is there error handling outside of this function? Can we put a try/catch block and catch the exception within this function?

Comment: The next question I asked was can we try this running as synchronously did it cause the same issue? I wouldn't rule out VS debugger having a memory leak(especially when doing async stuff), so can we run this app outside of VS but capture the error or check if the event viewer has anything to say? Just going thru process of elimination since there are many that can contribute to this issue. I agree with Moo-Juice that this is a very good question.